# jquery select remove item

Tags: jquery, select

My html code

```
<select name="test[]" id="test_0">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<select name="test[]" id="test_1">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

My jquery code

```
$("#test_0 option:eq(1)").remove();
$("#test_1 option:eq(2)").remove();
```

If I remove an item, how can I keep it in memory **to replace it later** at the **same place** ?

Thanks for your help...

Chris

Comment: @U-DON: `option` elements can't be hidden in some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide it:

```
 $("#test_0 option:eq(1)").hide();
 $("#test_1 option:eq(2)").hide();
```

But im not sure it works on all browsers. Otherwise you could clone it and save it in a variable and then remove it:

```
var option1 = $("#test_0 option:eq(1)").
var option1clone = option1.clone();
//now remove the original
option1.remove
```

Comment: Works fine but I have not tested in all browers. Thanks

Comment: @Chris: So you *don't* need to "replace it later at the same place"?

Comment: Yes. Doing $("#test_0 option:eq(1)").show(); after the 'hide' works fine on Firefox

Comment: @Chris: You perhaps could have mentioned that you're only supporting Firefox, and not other browsers.

Comment: @RightSaidFred : Well... I didn't know before I tested

Comment: @Chris: Well, you would have if you read the comment under your question, and... nevermind.

Answer (score 3):

Use .[detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead, it's better suited for reinserting elements at a later time as it preserves data and events attached to the element.

```
 var option =  $("#test_0 option:eq(1)").detach();
  $('#test_0').append(option);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question since this doesn't help to replace it later at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use for removing all other option except than one :-**

```
$("#test_0 option.not(':eq(1)').remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just hide them and show later when needed:

```
$("#test_0 option:eq(1)").hide();
//and for showing
$("#test_0 option:eq(1)").show();
```

Comment: If you down voted me in retaliation, your solution is broken. Don't take it personally. If you didn't, nevermind.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Like I said, if you didn't, nevermind. It was probably the other guy who deleted his answer.